# Show a hidden navbar when a short page is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a hidden navbar that shows up when you scroll down the page. However I want the navbar to automatically show for short pages which do not need any scrolling. Where am I going wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
 if ($(document).height() > $(window).height() )
  {
    $(document).on('scroll', function (e) {
      $('.topnavbar').css('opacity', ($(document).scrollTop() / 300));
      if ($('.topnavbar').css('opacity') > 0.8)
        { $('.topnavbar').css('opacity', 0.8); }
    });
  }
  else  {
   $('.topnavbar').css('opacity', 0.8); }
});
```

Comment: Your code is working as expected. What issue you are facing? I have created a jsfiddles for demo 

https://jsfiddle.net/7bvpnd1a/ - jsfiddle tor scrolling
https://jsfiddle.net/7bvpnd1a/1/ - jsfiddle for shorter pages without scrolling

Comment: I found the issue. It doesn't always load in my rails app when using link_to so I have used a gem to get around this.